Java spring boot jpa and oracle db is slow
I have question regarding slowly retrieving data from a database using java spring boot jpa - jbdc driver. I am new java programmer, so take it easy please :)
In DBeaver, simple select (without joins) takes less than 1s for 1700 rows.
In Java I prepared this code how to get data:

entity model definition
class DTO projection
interface projection
raw query using entity manager

Each of these solutions takes always more then 9s to return that 1700 rows.
In console output as log I can see same query as I tried in DBeaver.
I wrote also .net 9 application, which is fast as DBeaver. So I guess, there is something wrong with that jbdc or oracle driver configuration. I am not using bind parameters, only simple select statement. Do you have any ideas what could be the problem there?
In my opinion I had tried all possible ways, so I am asking java experts here if they can help me :)
Thanks
application.yaml configuration if it helps :)
spring:
  datasource:
    # connection data commented
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 20000
      idle-timeout: 300000
      max-lifetime: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      minimum-idle: 5
      validation-timeout: 3000
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      jdbc:
        fetch_size: 1000
      ddl-auto: none
      format_sql: true
      use_sql_comments: true 
      generate_statistics: true 
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
logging:
  level:
    com:
      test_package:
            my_app: INFO
      zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
    org.hibernate.stat: INFO

EDIT: Solved
Solution was in fetchData settings. It takes by default 10 rows (I understand it in that way).
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(...);
List<Object[]> results = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class).setFetchSize(1000).getResultList();

Unwrap with fetchData is the solution.

What does raw query using entity manager mean?  Is the findAll() method being used?  Please add some more code.

Solution was in fetchData settings. It takes by default 10 rows (I understand it in that way).
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(...);
List<Object[]> results = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class).setFetchSize(1000).getResultList();

Unwrap with fetchData is the solution.
